# TypeError: $(...).mmenu is not a function

Tags: jquery, mmenu

I use the [jquery.mmenu](https://mmenujs.com) plugin as a hamburger menu:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery.mmenu';

$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#mobileMenu').mmenu();
});
```

This works. But I have included jquery already trough a cdn:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
```

So if I remove: `import $ from 'jquery';`. I get:

> TypeError: $(...).mmenu is not a function

How do I have to write this in order to not include jquery twice?

Comment: Remove the `<script>`. Including a second copy of jQuery removes the previous one and any plugins registered

Comment: I don't want to remove th script. I down want to include jquery into the same file

Comment: You can simply use cdn version of `mmenu` instead

Answer (score 2):

Just add jquery in top of the libraries

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jQuery.mmenu/6.1.0/jquery.mmenu.all.js"></script>
```